# Which amount of money can we pay out exactly with 4 pieces of 5 cent, 1 piece of 10 cent and 2 pieces of 20 cent?(without change)

Tags: combinatorics

I think that the polinom $(1+x^5+x^{10}+x^{15}+x^{20})(1+x^{10})(1+x^{20}+x^{40})$ describes pretty well the problem. Is that true? If I expand this polinom can I get the correct answer?

Comment: Looks fine.${}$

Answer (score 0):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Arthur remarked in a comment, this looks fine.